# OnClick method does not start new activity

Tags: android, android-activity, onclick, onclicklistener

This code isn't calling the next activity. I don't understand why, but this onClick method isn't starting the next activity, though the same code in other activities does. Tested calling other activities and it didn't work even. The button is created, but when I tap it, nothing happens.

Edit: Folks, when we make a question about code, we want to know what is wrong, why is wrong, how to fix and why and this fixing works. We want to understand both the problem and the solution, and just drop a sample of code alone as an answer doesn't quite help some people. I thank you all for spending time with my question and for helping me solve this issue, but keep this words in mind when you are answering someone's question.

```
package com.example.conjuradortormenta;


import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

public class ListadePersonagens extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_listade_personagens);

        LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(this);
        layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

        // Using shared preferences, we get information about the characters
        SharedPreferences informacoesdepersonagem = getSharedPreferences("com.example.conjuradortormenta_informaçoes_de_personagem", MODE_PRIVATE);
        int num = informacoesdepersonagem.getInt("numero_de_personagens", 0);
        String nome, resumo;

        Button botao[]= new Button[num+1];

        if(num!=0)
        {
            for(int i=1; i<=num; i++)// cria os botões de cada personagem
            {
                nome = informaçõesdepersonagem.getString("nome_personagem"+(i+1), "Nenhum");
                resumo = informaçõesdepersonagem.getString("raça_personagem"+(i+1), "Nenhum")+ " " + informaçõesdepersonagem.getString("classe_personagem"+(i+1), "Nenhum") + " " + Integer.toString(informaçõesdepersonagem.getInt("nivel_personagem"+(i+1), 0));

                botao[i]=new Button(this);
                botao[i].setText(nome+" "+resumo);
                botao[i].setId(i);

                botao[i].setOnClickListener(this);
                layout.addView(botao[i]);
            }
        }

        botao[0]=new Button(this);
        botao[0].setText("Criar Novo");
        botao[0].setId(1);

        botao[0].setOnClickListener(this);

        layout.addView(botao[0]);
    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View view)
    {
        Intent nova = new Intent (this, CriadordePersonagem.class);
        startActivity(nova);
    }



}
```

Comment: Your code seems to be working and click event is also getting executed so might be the issue is like the layout file for your next activity is the same as your previous one that's why you are not getting any changes. just a possibility not sure

Comment: @MohitDholakia no, is not, the layout is diferent

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to add a bunch of buttons to your `LinearLayout`, but you don't actually add `layout` to your view hierarchy. Can you try calling `setContentView(layout)` and clicking on the buttons then?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use this example :-

```
     public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
         @Override
         protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
             super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
             setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            Button button = findViewById(R.id.button);
            button.setOnClickListener(this);
         }
        @Override
         public void onClick(View v) {
             switch (v.getId())
             {
                 case R.id.button:
                    startActivity(new Intent(this, Doctor.class));
                    break;
             }
         }
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

Would be useful to see your XML `layout`, but my first guess is that you didn't add the layout anywhere.

Your `layout` seems to be `R.layout.activity_listade_personagens` so if you want to edit it, you should get it instead of creating a new one:

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_listade_personagens);

LinearLayout layout = findViewById(R.layout.activity_listade_personagens);

layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
// Rest of your code
```

Comment: When I try to do it, the activity doesn't even start. When the button in MainActivity that should call ListadePersonagens is pressed, the app closes

Answer (score 0):

In **onClick** method, you did not get Id of which view be clicked. So android cannot know **onClick** for what view. You should do that:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View view){
    switch (view.getId()){
        case R.id.button:
            Intent nova = new Intent (this, CriadordePersonagem.class);
            startActivity(nova);
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(OneActivity.this, TwoActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);

        }
    });
```